# Drop leading rows of Pandas Dataframe containing NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Prior to cleaning up a Pandas Dataframe of a time series, I want to drop the rows at the top that contain `NaN` in certain columns.

I wanted to iterate over the start of the dataframe and drop the rows that meet the condition where column is `NaN`.  My dataframe below is called "train", and contains two columns - 'Date', and 'Maximum temperature (Degree C)'.  I set Date to the Index.  The initial 20 odd rows contain `NaN` in 'Maximum temperature (Degree C)'.

```
#Drop NaN values at start of dataframe

for date,row in train.iterrows():
  print(date)
  if train.loc[date,'Maximum temperature (Degree C)']==np.nan:
      train.drop(index=date, inplace=True)
  else:
    break
```

I expected the code would drop the rows from the start of the dataframe, but my `if` statement doesn't pick up the `NaN`, so it breaks after the first row.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dropping you can use, you can use `first_valid_index()` as follows

```
import pandas as pd 

# dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[None, None, 2, 4, 5], 
                   "B":[None, None, None, 44, 2], 
                   "C":[None, None, None, 1, 5]}) 


df.C.first_valid_index()
```

Output:

```
3
```

then use

```
df.loc[2:]
```

OR

```
df[df.C.first_valid_index():]
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
3   4.0  44.0  1.0
4   5.0  2.0   5.0
```

Hope this helps